# Cross-Farm Social Features in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, deployment, my-site, social, activity-feed

We have two separate SP2010 Farms, Farm-A has a "TeamSite" web-application and "Mysite" is hosted on Farm-B.

User Profile service is hosted on Farm-B and consumed in Farm-A.

**My Requirement is:**
    When a user post a Tag or notes on the Teamsite, the feed should be visible on the Mysite.

Is there any specific setting required in this case? I hope, Tags and Notes will be stored in the Social DB and activity feed will be generated, so no other changes/settings are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to consume the User Profile Application hosted on the separate Farm.

**Steps:**
1. Taken the Profile DB & Social DB.
2. Created a new UPS on the UPS-Farm, used the DB backups.
3. Configured the UPA.
4. Published and consumed UPA on the Teamsite-Farm.